# How to implement https redirect to a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I am facing something odd. I have this in my htaccess file under blog directory and I am redirecting only specific folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.admuuv.com/blog/$1 [R,L]
```

When I write this to browser https://admuuv.com/blog/digital-signage-yazilimindan-alinacak-12-fayda/  it seems ok, but when I delete 's' near 'http' and hit enter forces the url to redirect 'https' but the 'blog' got missed and I get 404 error. Why the blog directory disappears? Why It doesn't just reload the page (by forcing https rule) and keep showing the content? How can I accomplish this? You can observe it from the link also.
[image: 404 error 'blog' missing]

Comment: Use the Redirect directive for this, don't abuse mod_rewrite. We don't do this for like 10 years now.

Comment: @Cheatah Ok but how?

Comment: It has to do with `Redirect` and `/blog` and `https://www.admuuv.com/blog`.